# Unix jq parsing wildcards

Tags: json, jq

I have a json output with dozens of entries following this format:

```
{
  "a": {
    "1": {
      "c": "text1"
    },
dozens more ...
    "999": {
      "c": "text99"
    }
  }
}
```

I want the "c" value for each
Something like:
".a.*.c"
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.a | .[] | .c
```

which can be abbreviated as:

```
.a[].c
```

### Value of all .c keys

If you wanted the value of all keys named "c", no matter where they occur:

```
.. | .c? // empty
```

Comment: jq --slurpfile newval auth.json '.paths | .. | objects | .get.parameters += $newval' test.json > test1.json