# JQ - Deep child value replace through wildcard search and merge to the original JSON

Tags: json, linux, jq

My question is similar to [Unix jq parsing wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389347/unix-jq-parsing-wildcards) but want to merge to the original JSON.

Say, input JSON:

```
{
  "a": {
    "1": {
      "c": "text1"
    },
    "999": {
      "c": "text99"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to manipulate the inner `"c": "text1"` and modify it to `"c": "newtext"`. But, also need to merge with the original JSON. IOW, it is not about extracting, but about manipulating.

Expected output:

```
{
  "a": {
    "1": {
      "c": "newtext"
    },
    "999": {
      "c": "text99"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried:

```
.. | .c? |= (sub("^text1$";"newtext"))
```

But, it throws `null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string`

jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/2nFAus6Umz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `walk` the path with the expression to select an object type when `.c` equals to your desired value

```
jq 'walk(if type == "object" and .c == "text1" then .c |= "newtext" else . end)'
```

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/QA2Nkuajgr)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Unfortunately, I don't have reputation to either upvote or accept the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rajesh - If you can ask a question, then you should be able to "accept" it.

Comment: Now only the option is available and I accepted yours.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of your attempt:

```
(.. | objects | select(has("c")) | .c) |= (sub("^text1$";"newtext"))
```

or in order of increasing brevity:

```
(.. | select(try has("c")) | .c) |= (sub("^text1$";"newtext"))

(.. | select(has("c")?) | .c) |= (sub("^text1$";"newtext"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice new syntax and explanation. Unfortunately, couldn't upvote due to reputation issue. Thanks again!