# JQ - Deep child replace through wildcard search, but check parent presence with merge to the original JSON

Tags: json, linux, jq

This is a kind of extension to my previous question [JQ - Deep child value replace through wildcard search and merge to the original JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818537/jq-deep-child-value-replace-through-wildcard-search-and-merge-to-the-original)

I want to check the presence of a particular key in some parents before replacing the child. *Loosely*, translated to CSS selector, I want something like `* > fixedKeyCheckPresence > * > fixedKeyCheckValue`

**Input:**

```
{
  "randomKey1": {
    "randomKey2": [
      {
        "randomKeyUnderAnyLevel11": {
          "fixedKeyCheckPresence": {
            "randomeKeyUnderAnyLevel23": {
              "fixedKeyCheckValue": "Foo"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "randomKey11": {
    "fixedKeyCheckPresence": {
      "randomeKeyUnderAnyLevel123": {
        "fixedKeyCheckValue": "Foo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
  "randomKey1": {
    "randomKey2": [
      {
        "randomKeyUnderAnyLevel11": {
          "fixedKeyCheckPresence": {
            "randomeKeyUnderAnyLevel23": {
              "fixedKeyCheckValue": "Bar"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "randomKey11": {
    "fixedKeyCheckPresence": {
      "randomeKeyUnderAnyLevel123": {
        "fixedKeyCheckValue": "Bar"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Tried:** `(.. | select(try has("fixedKeyCheckPresence")) | .fixedKeyCheckValue) |= (sub("^Foo$";"Bar"))`

**jq play:** https://jqplay.org/s/_YlLSyTEc7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `walk` with `..` :

```
jq 'walk(
        (.fixedKeyCheckPresence? | .. |
         select(has("fixedKeyCheckValue")?).fixedKeyCheckValue) |= sub("^Foo$";"Bar")
    )' input.json
```

`.fixedKeyCheckPresence?` takes care of find the object key `fixedKeyCheckPresence` and leaves everything else intact.

Then under `.fixedKeyCheckPresence`, we enumerate all sub-nodes with `..` and select the object containing `fixedKeyCheckValue`.

Comment: This works great for my example https://jqplay.org/s/LDWTj1u6h0 and so accepted your answer. Thanks for your help. But, could you please confirm if it really checks for the parent? Also, how is the ".." and "?" works here? Any additional explanation on how it works is welcome. Thanks again

Comment: You can easily check regarding parent by renaming the second `fixedKeyCheckPresence` to `fooBar`.